# persistent login cookie, avoiding spam, and using yahoo facebook ids

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, authentication, openid

I am writing a java servlet + javascript (ext4) application, that in some ways behaves like a forum.

My hibernate tables use a login id of type long throughout.  Rather than requiring my own registration and password mechanism, I would like to use Facebook and Yahoo ids, but it can't be PHP based (I hope).  I've heard of OpenID, but I'm wondering how websites are doing this now.

Also, with a persistent login id cookie, how do I keep it safe to prevent spammers from making unwanted posts?  I want to avoid tomcat sessions if possible, or at least use them in an intelligent way to basically allow the appearance of sessionless use of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) for open id authentication . Read [this](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364125/Using-OpenID) article for help .  Also [Spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-openid) supports open-ID.